# PHP grab content function, inside meta tags?

Tags: php, meta, schema.org

I'm trying to improve my site structure, per Schema.

So I have:

```
<div class="post">
<?php the_content() ?>
</div>
```

And I want something like:

```
<div class="post">
<meta itemprop="articleBody" content="<?php the_content() ?>">
</div>
```

But that removes images from the content, and appends `">`.. So I'm aware I'm not closing it properly. But how do I "make the PHP stop", and be contained within the `content=""` tags?

Thanks,

Comment: If it contains HTML and content, it's probably not meta data that should be invisible. Though you're possibly just asking for escaping: `htmlspecialchars()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, I got it!

Sort of. I just approached it wrong (to be fair, I was mislead by by the recommendation in Google's WMT), for anyone else:

The tag should be inside the `div` container, not `meta` at all (that came from WMT):

```
<div itemprop="articleBody" class="post">
     <?php the_content() ?> 
</div>
```